# AWS DynamoDB query not filtering on BOOL value

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a users table that was create with the GUI and given a partion key of email and it is a string. I then used aws lambda to do a putItem that had:

```
email (string) test@testing.com
deleted (BOOL) false
```

This worked fine. I then tried to query it with lambda using the following params and query:

```
var params =
{
    TableName : 'Users', 
    KeyConditionExpression : 'email = :email',
    FilterExpression : 'deleted = :deleted',
    ExpressionAttributeValues :
    {
        ':email' : email,
        ':deleted':
        {
            BOOL: false
        }
    }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data)
{
    if (err) return fn(err);
    else
    {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

This always returns 0 items when I search for email = test@testing.com and leave the deleted as false. If I remove the filter expression of deleted I get an item return so why doesn't the BOOL = false work or should I use something else?

Comment: Can you show your DynamoDB sample data? I am wondering whether you have deleted field with BOOL data type.

Comment: Yes I do. How do you check in the dynamodb gui what datatypes the items are?

Comment: The filter in the gui appears to only allow queries of string, binary or number

Comment: The attribute should be prefixed with the type.

Comment: Can you filter by email and show the screen shot of the item?

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/Jh5ubsiml

Comment: i guess you cannot use bool and need to use a number instead

Comment: Show the console log content what you have got when you execute the code without Filterexpression

Comment: deleted is set to false and the gui only lets me enter true or false in the db http://screencast.com/t/D30WJ1DJbE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the code to filter `BOOL` data. It is not required to code like below as DynamoDB interpret it as BOOL value inside MAP data type.

```
{ BOOL: false        }
```

**Change to:-**

```
':deleted' :  false
```

**Code:-**

```
var table = "users";

var params = {
    TableName : table,
    KeyConditionExpression : 'email = :email',
    FilterExpression: 'deleted = :deleted',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':email' : 'abc@gmail.com',
        ':deleted' :  false
    }   
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

**My DynamoDB item which has BOOL data:-**

[image]