# Query on AWS DynamoDB for Boolean and Date ranges

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, nosql

I have 2 problems. I want to query a dynamodb database on Bool and on Date.

Is this possible as I only see String Number and Binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of expressions.

KeyConditionExpression - Supports only String, Number and Binary

FilterExpression - Can be used for Non-Key attributes. You can query for the Date and BOOL attributes.

There is a `BETWEEN` operator which can be used for DATE range as well.

**Code to filter by Date:-**

```
var params = {
    TableName : table,
    KeyConditionExpression : 'email = :email',
    FilterExpression: 'createdAt = :createdAt',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':email' : 'abc@gmail.com',
        ':createdAt' :  "2016-11-07"
    }   
};
```

**My Item:-**

Date is stored as String in database.

> Date  S (string type). The Date values are stored as ISO-8601 formatted
>   strings.

[image: DynamoDB Item]

Comment: I cannot get FilterExpression to query for Bool or Date

Comment: See this other post I have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461910/aws-dynamodb-query-not-filtering-on-bool-value

Comment: You haven't answered the other post

Comment: other stack posters seem to exprience the same issue too

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is some nasty hack on the DynamoDB side. I'd use integer timestamp and query that. Can't fool a number.